# PayPal sandbox vs live account

Tags: paypal

I want to integrate PayPal payments on my client's website.
I logged in **my** paypal account and created an App to test their REST API. Everything's fine and works good.
Now I have to go live, and here's my question: if I use **my** API live credentials, when someone makes a purchase the money will be accredited to **my** paypal account instead of the client's one?
Or do I have to ask my client his paypal credentials to create an App from his account? Or...what else?

Dumb question, I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out that I just forgot to do the simplest thing, read the doc:
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/permissions-outside

Thanks anyway, Marius.

Answer (score 0):

The REST API I'm quite sure only gives you access to accept other peoples credit cards and other peoples paypal-accouts to transfer money to you. So your first question-statement should be correct.

If unsure, or if I might have misunderstood, you can find alot about it on the REST API Reference [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/).

Comment: So my second question should be the way to go, right?

Comment: As far as I know, yes, you should create it with your clients credentials.